# Get updated polygon points after transformations (SVG)

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there any function or method to get updated points in a SVG polygon after applying transformations? I'm doing transformations in JavaScript and I noticed points still the same after transformations.

```
function drawPolygon(){

    var points = "100,100 200,100 200,200 100,200";
    var polygon = document.createElementNS(svgURL, "polygon");
    polygon.setAttribute("style", "fill: gray; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; cursor: pointer;");

    polygon.setAttribute("points", points);

    mySVG.appendChild(polygon);

    console.log(polygon.points);
    // Points: 100,100 200,100 200,200 100,200

    polygon.setAttribute("transform", "translate(200,0)");

    console.log(polygon.points);
    //Points: 100,100 200,100 200,200 100,200
}
```

How can I get updated points like: 300, 100, 400, 100 400, 200 300, 200 or get another polygon with updated points?

Edited: The first answer from Francis Hemsher is working well if we don't have a viewbox, now I'm having a problem, I have a viewbox in my svg:

```
<svg id="my_svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" style="background-color: lightblue">

</svg>

function drawRoom(){

    var points = "-100,0 100,0 100,100 -100,100";

    var polygon = document.createElementNS(svgURL, "polygon");
    polygon.setAttribute("style", "fill: gray; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; cursor: pointer;");

    polygon.setAttribute("points", points);

    mySVG.appendChild(polygon);

    //Points: "-100,0 100,0 100,100 -100,100";
    polygon.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,-50)");

    screenPolygon(polygon);

    //Points should be: "-100,-50 100,-50 100,50 -100,50" if I apply function provided by Francis

    //But points are: "50, 100 250,100 250,200 50,200"

}
```

[polygon after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVfoW.png)

[polygon after apply function screenPolygon(myPoly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoNcu.png)

Please do you know how can I get updated points like in figure 1, I know the viewbox have something to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function screenPolygon(myPoly)
{
 var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
 var svgRoot = myPoly.ownerSVGElement

 var pointsList = myPoly.points;
 var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
 for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
 {
  var mySVGPoint = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
  mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
  mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
  mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
  pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
  pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
 }
 //---force removal of transform--
 myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
 myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the setAttribute call immediately prior to removeAttribute? Also I think you can iterate with "for (var item of myPoly.points)" these days.

Comment: @RobertLongson FYI, older versions of IE do not remove the transform using only removeAttribute, but, for some reason, it had to be empty before it was removed.

Comment: Thank you @FrancisHemsher, is exactly what I need.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher I'm having another problem (now svg has viewbox), I edited the question, can you give me some help ?